# Ownership of chometz by public entity

Tags: halacha, organizations

If a non profit organization owns chometz do they need to sell it/get rid of it for pesach? I would think not being that legally there is no owner of the organization (no body making a profit, owning the real estate…) and as such there is no person to be Jewish and to be obligated in Halacha. Which would lead to a funny outcome that everyone could sell their chometz to their local shul for pesach.

Comment: Reb Moshe has a *teshuvah* on the halachical status of corporate ownership. Recognising a corporation as a separate entity to the shareholders is a modern innovation at any rate. For example, the gemara considers people in a town to be *shutfim* in the ownership of the *sifrei torah* in their *shul*.

Comment: I remember that question coming up in regards to Hilchos RIbbis.